# Python Regex For Capturing Dates in Url

Tags: python, regex, date

I'm trying to scrape dates from URL's of blogs and the like.
Since there's no universal way to get a date, I am for now, relying
on the date to be in the URL of the resource.

The dates come for the most part, in  these formats:

```
url1 = "foo/bar/baz/2014/01/01/more/text"
url2 = "foo/bar/baz/2014/01/more/text"
url3 = "foo/bar/baz/20140101/more/text"
url4 = "foo/bar/baz/2014-01-01/more/text"
url5 = "foo/bar/baz/2014-01more/text"
url6 = "foo/bar/baz/2014_01_01/more/text"
url7 = "foo/bar/baz/2014_01/more/text"

# forgot one
url8 = "foo/bar/baz20140101more/text"
```

I've written a brute force code to get what I want.
It's explicit, but not elegant and probably not very robust.

I'd tried to cover the cases where I match "\" or "-" or "_" with no luck.
So I'm curious as to how one does that.

**Although my main question is:** 
What's the best robust way to capture dates in a URL with the intention of converting them to datetime objects.

I don't think it's common for time elements to be in the format.

Cheers !

**UPDATE**

I believe I have the solution from Casimer. I'd like to add one more
url-date format that I missed before and might add a little trouble:

```
# this one maynot have a regex solution. Maybe machine learning. 
# and it's not that big a deal if I get the wrong day for this application.
# I think it's safe to assume, that a legit date with Y/M/d with have
# /Y/m/d/   trailing "/" 
http://www.nakedcapitalism.com/2014/03/17-million-reasons-rent-control-efficient.html
2014/03/17 # group captured
2014-03-17 00:00:00 # date time object


http://www.nakedcapitalism.com/2014/11/200pm-water-cooler-11514.html
2014/11/20
2014-11-20 00:00:00

# i put more restrictions on the number matching, but perhaps there's a better way...?

pat = r'(20[0-1][0-5]([-_/]?)[0-1][0-9]\2[0-3][0-9])'
```

**Existing ugly solution:**

NOTE: I've restricted the year info, because I was capturing strings of numbers that do not represent a date. Plus I figured it was more robust that way.

```
def get_date_from_url(self, url):
    #pat = "(20[0-14]{2}\w+[0-9]{2}(?!\w+[0-9]{2}))"
    pat = "(20[0-1][0-5]/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})"
    ob1 = re.compile(pat)

    pat = "(20[0-1][0-5]-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})"
    ob2 = re.compile(pat)

    pat = "(20[0-1][0-5]_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2})"
    ob3 = re.compile(pat)

    pat = "(20[0-1][0-5]/[0-9]{2})"
    ob4 = re.compile(pat)

    pat = "(20[0-1][0-5]-[0-9]{2})"
    ob5 = re.compile(pat)

    pat = "(20[0-1][0-5]_[0-9]{2})"
    ob6 = re.compile(pat)

    if ob1.search(url):
        grp = ob1.search(url).group()

    elif ob2.search(url):
        grp = ob2.search(url).group()

    elif ob3.search(url):
        grp = ob3.search(url).group()

    elif ob4.search(url):
        grp = ob4.search(url).group()

    elif ob5.search(url):
        grp = ob5.search(url).group()

    elif ob6.search(url):
        grp = ob6.search(url).group()

    else:
        return None

    print url
    print grp
    grp = re.sub('_', '/', grp) # fail to match return orig string
    date = to_datetime(grp)

    if isinstance(date, datetime.datetime):
        print date

    else:
        return None
```

Comment: In the future, a site like [Regexr](http://regexr.com/) will help you write and debug regex patterns easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
pat = r'(20[0-1][0-5]([-_/]?)[0-9]{2}(?:\2[0-9]{2})?)'
```

the delimiter is captured in group 2, so I use a backreference `\2` for the second delimiter. The delimiter can be `-` `_` or `/` but is optional too (with the `?` quantifier).

This makes the day optional too by putting it in an optional non-capturing group: `(?:\2[0-9]{2})?`

Note that you can add the slashes at the begining and at the end to ensure that the date are enclosed between paths.

Comment: @wbg: the `?` means zero or one (so it makes the character class optional).

Comment: haha, I just looked that ? up in the doc...the use of a back-reference I've not seen before...and I thought I was getting better at regex :/

Comment: @wbg: the back-reference is defined by the round brackets ( and ) and not the ?. A ? has two different meanings: optionality (0 or 1) or greediness.